# Java to create XML and using XSL to create HTML escaped characters

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I have a bit of an issue

1. Get user data with java
2. Generate XML using JAXB
3. Create my XSL template
4. Use Java to generate the HTML

Now i have an issue with `\r` and `\n` and some other funky symbols.  Should i parse the content of my xml with xml escapes or html escapes. The default Java escape utility class is doing a piss poor job of it and the custom class i found online isn't working either.

Would a good solution be to just replace `\n` and `\r` with `<p> </p>` or what `html tag` would be a good choice? Thank you!

A simple example would be my date value in my xml which was passed in as a string and all escapes were used.

**Original:**  (same time, i don't remember which)
 - `Mon, 29 Feb 2016 13:40:58 EST (-0500)`

**Escaped XML entry:** 
 - `<Date>Mon&amp;#044; 29 Feb 2016 03&amp;#058;40&amp;#058;43 EST&amp;#040;&amp;#045;0500&amp;#041;</Date>`

**Parsed HTML output:** 
 - `Mon&#044; 29 Feb 2016 03&#058;40&#058;43 EST&#040;&#045;0500&#041;`

Something clearly went wrong in the encoding and decoding of the special characters.
but when this is parsed into html

EDIT: I also have this junk which i don't even recognize was: `&#xD;`

**EDIT:** I fixed the date issue but it's still not encoding properly in parts.

```
public static String entityEncode(String text) {
    String result = text;
    if (result == null)
        return result;
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(XMLStringUtil.escapeControlChrs(result));
}
```

And the other class is:

```
public class XMLStringUtil {

    private static HashSet<Character> illegalChrSet = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        final String illegalChrs = "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005" +
                "\u0006\u0007\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E\u000F\u0010\u0011\u0012" +
                "\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001A\u001B\u001C" +
                "\u001D\u001E\u001F\uFFFE\uFFFF";

        for (int i=0; i < illegalChrs.length(); i++) {
            illegalChrSet.add(illegalChrs.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    public static String escapeControlChrs(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
        for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char chr = str.charAt(i);
            if (illegalChrSet.contains(chr)) {
                sb.append("\\x");
                sb.append(String.format("%04x", (int) chr));
            } else {
                sb.append(chr);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String removeControlChrs(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
        for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char chr = str.charAt(i);
            if (! illegalChrSet.contains(chr)) {
                sb.append(chr);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

but i still get this junk in the xml:

```
<Info>The origin domain used for comparison was: &#xD;
google.ca.ca&#xD;
blah blah blah&#xD;
</Info>
```

It occurs on new lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are encoding to xml itself. HTML is parsing the values properly. For html & is &. Please check how you are encoding to xml. XML should not be having all those ascii chars.

basically your string is having the character '/'. when encoded it is getting converted to  for xml. This  is not known to html. Either when creating xml replace '/' with / and when decoded html will automatically convert to '/'

Comment: I updated the question to show you how i'm encoding now, but still some issues :(